# Test if variable contains newline (POSIX)

Tags: shell, string, posix, newlines, dash

I know that some shells accept this kind of test:

```
t() { [[ $var == *$'\n'* ]] && res=yes || res=no
      printf '%s ' "$res";
    }

var='ab
cd'
t
var='abcd'
t
echo
```

on execution:

```
$ bash ./script
yes no
```

1. What is the POSIX (dash) working equivalent
2. Is the following a reliable way to test?

   ```
   nl='
   '

   t() {  case "$var" in
              *$nl* ) res=yes ;;
              * ) res=no ;;
          esac
          printf '%s ' "$res"
        }

   var='ab
   cd'
   t
   var='abcd'
   t
   echo
   ```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can put a hard newline in a variable, and pattern match with `case`.

```
$ cat nl.sh
#!/bin/sh
nl='
'
case "$1" in
    *$nl*)  echo has newline ;;
    *)      echo no newline  ;;
esac

$ dash nl.sh $'foo\nbar'
has newline
$ dash nl.sh $'foobar'
no newline
```

The alternative way to make the newline is something like this:

```
nl=$(printf "\nx"); nl=${nl%x}
```

The obvious command substitution doesn't work because trailing newlines are removed by the substitution.

Answer (score 4):

Yes,

```
nl='
'
case $var in
  (*"$nl"*) echo yes;;
  (*)       echo no;;
esac
```

(by principle, I like to quote all variable expansions inside `case` pattern unless I want them to be treated as a pattern, though here it doesn't make a difference as `$nl` does not contain wildcards).

or

```
case $var in
  (*'
'*) echo yes;;
  (*) echo no;;
esac
```

Should all work and are POSIX compliant, and what I would use for that. If you remove the `(`s, it would even work in the old Bourne shell.

For another way to set the `$nl` variable:

```
eval "$(printf 'nl="\n"')"
```

Note that [`$'\n'` is planned for inclusion in the next version of the POSIX standard](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=249). It's already supported by `ksh93`, `zsh`, `bash`, `mksh`, busybox and FreeBSD `sh` at least (as of February 2018).

As for whether the test you have is enough, you've got a test for both cases so would be testing all the code paths.

There's currently something that is not clearly specified in the POSIX spec: whether `*` matches on a string that contains byte sequences that don't form valid characters or whether shell variables may contain those strings.

In practice, apart from `yash` whose variables can only contain characters, and apart from the NUL bytes (which no shell but `zsh` can store  in their variables), `*$nl*` should match on any string that contains `$nl` even if they contain sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters (like `$'\x80'` in UTF-8).

Some `find` implementations for instance would fail to match with `-name "*$nl*"` on  them, so if testing a new shell, and if you intend to deal with things that are not guaranteed to be text (like filenames), you may want to add a test case for it. Like with with:

```
test=$(printf '\200\n\200')
```

in a UTF-8 locale.